# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error AngularJS 1.4.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I'm getting an error on load of my Angular App. I have this inside my django app.

**Here's my code:**

**HTML:**

```
 {% extends "food_app/common/base.html" %}
 {% load staticfiles %}


{% block js %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/home.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div ng-app="home_app">

<div ng-controller="home_controller">


    <md-content>
        <input ng-model="message2">
        {$ message $}
        {$ message2 $}
    </md-content>

   </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('home_app', ['services','ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
```

I've loaded already all the required stuff for the project which is located in `{% load staticfiles %}`. I just simply extended this from my base.

So now I just loaded my JS for this page in home.js. But I can't seem to connect to my app.

**I'm getting this error:**

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]      http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=home_app&p1=Error%3…p%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)
```

Error Stack

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module home_app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr]    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=s...)
at Error (native)
at http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/lib/js/angular.min.js:6:416
at http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/lib/js/angular.min.js:38:391
at n (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/lib/js/angular.min.js:7:333)
at g (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/lib/js/angular.min.js:37:488)
at http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/lib/js/angular.min.js:38:134
at n (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/lib/js/angular.min.js:7:333)
at g (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/lib/js/angular.min.js:37:488)
at eb (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/lib/js/angular.min.js:41:249)
at c (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/lib/js/angular.min.js:19:463
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack? Usually this error means it cannot find some dependency.

Comment: @Bolza There it is